# Show div when there is an error

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

So I got this div

```
#create-transaction-container {
  padding: $padding;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba($dark-blue-color,0.95), rgba($dark-blue-color,0.7));
  border-radius: $border-radius;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: $margin-bottom; 
}
```

And it is showing when I click a button

```
function showDiv() {
    $('#create-transaction-container').fadeIn(750)
}
```

But as I enter in some input and it returns any errors when submitting I want the div to show automatically so the user can see the errors immediately without having to click on the button again.

So I thought I found the solution on SO but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Anyone can help?

This is my haml code for display the error

```
%span.error
  = flash[:error]
```

And this is the solution I thought might work

```
if ($('.error').length) {  // return's true if element is present
    // show or hide another div
    $('#create-transaction-container').show();
}
```

Comment: Could you update to complete run able code to test!!

Comment: When does content get added to the span.error element? It might be empty

Comment: @Sanity11234 As soon as an error occurs. For example when a textfield is empty

Answer (score 0):

`window.onerror` is triggered whether it was a syntax or runtime error. You can documnetation regarding this event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror);

```
element.onerror = function(event) { ... }
```